# Template for resizing arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string, templates

I am trying to write a template class with functions for a class of arrays.
I put something together that seems to work for int, float, double, but will not work for strings.  I included , and am using namespace std.

Everything compiles, and works fine unless I use strings, in which case it errors at the resize function.

in the header file I have the following relevant code (because everything compiles and the error only exists HERE):

```
template<typename T>
void Array<T>::resize(int newSize)
{
    T* newArray = new T[newSize];
    if (newSize >= mSize)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newSize; ++i)
            newArray[i] = mData[i];
    }
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
            newArray[i] = mData[i];
    delete[] mData;
    mData = new T[newSize];
    mSize = newSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; ++i)
        mData[i] = newArray[i];
    delete[] newArray;
    newArray = 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Your code seems really redundant and needs refactoring.

Comment: I am a novice and trying to learn with the tools I currently know.  I know that I will get better and more efficient with practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
T* newArray = new T[newSize];
if (newSize >= mSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; ++i)
        newArray[i] = mData[i];
}
```

Notice that if the new size is greater than the old size, you iterate from 0 up to `newSize` reading values from the old array. The problem is that the old array only has indices that are valid from 0 to `mSize - 1`, not from 0 to `newSize - 1`, so this reads off the end of the array. This leads to undefined behavior in all cases (oops!), but for primitive types this typically doesn't cause a crash and you'd only see this for strings.

You might want to look at the rest of your code to make sure the loop bounds are correct, since I think you'll find at least one more loop that isn't set up properly.

Also, consider looking at tools like `valgrind`, which are excellent at diagnosing memory errors like these.

As a complete incidental finding, you might also want to think about whether you need to do two allocations and two deallocations. Can you do this with just one new allocation and one deallocation?

Comment: Other than valgrind, I'd recommend using the Clang Sanitizers. I personally prefer Clang's Santizers to valgrind, and some of them are easy to use in gcc as well

Comment: Thanks, that helped.  I looked at the code and I suppose what I did wrong was reverse the newSize and mSize, where I was essentially iterating nothing.  I changed it to be:  "if larger, write set the new size and write up to what we have" so the remaining indexes are null, and conversely only "write up to the newSize" when the  new Size is smaller.  Works now!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mData` is of type `T*`, you can try this something like:

```
template<typename T>
void Array<T>::resize(int newSize)
{       
    if (newSize == mSize) {
        return;
    }
    T* newArray = new T[newSize];
    if (newSize < mSize) {
        memcpy(newArray, mData, newSize * sizeof(T));
    } else {
        memset(newArray, 0, mSize * sizeof(T));
        memcpy(newArray, mData, mSize * sizeof(T));
    }
    delete[] mData;
    mData = newArray;
    mSize = newSize;
}
```

Key points:

- if size is the same as previously, then there is no resize!
- You only copy once, and through a standard memcpy
- This function is type agnostic and can be used in all your templates resize features
- Memory is whiped with memset() when the resized array is larger, to avoid memory leak

Comment: Wouldn't `std::fill` and `std::copy` essentially do the same thing, except more type-safely?

Comment: I was trying to write it with the limited tools I know right now.  Have not learned memset/memcpy yet.  I am sure those will make my life much easier!